# Block IP from multiple access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix

Is there any way to block an IP that have already visited a site with htaccess other any other tools?
Like someone visited a this site www.my-site.com/index1.html and I want to prevent that he can visit it again what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

or you can deny a lock like this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx
```

xxx is obviously the octet

Comment: Yes I am aware of this but I only want to block them if they already have visited my site :(

Comment: So if they visit once you do not want them to visit again? You are not trying to block abuse?

Comment: Yes thats right. No for abuse I would use anything like ufw or fail2ban .

Comment: You could read your access logs or store visited IPs and process them on the server, appending your htaccess periodically. Although all that sounds a bit heavy. Why not set a session cookie variable and redirect them to a 'Sorry' page if they try to access again.

Comment: No, you must use javascript for client side cookie, or php or similar for a session. But his is the simplest route, there will always be a way around it and if you block one IP you could block multiple users if they going through a proxy.